# Is there a way to have function parameter type based on generic parameter type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, generic-type-argument, generic-type-parameters

I have a generics parameterize type for a function that returns the property of the global object.

```js
type Store = {
  "first": number;
  "second": boolean;
  "third": string;
}

declare function namespaced<S extends Record<string, any>, N extends keyof S>(namespace: N): S[N];

let p = namespaced<Store, "first">("first");
```

Since the `namespace` parameter has type of `keyof S`, I thought it would be possible to omit the second type in the function definition, and my code would look like this:

```js
let p = namespaced<Store>("first");
```

However this gives me the error:

> Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1.(2558)

Is it possible to achieve it **without changing the function**?

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nr4Z2W)

Comment: If you can't change the function then how do you expect anything to change?  What *are* you allowed to change?  I mean, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleZem) is how you'd do it and I didn't change the function (but I expect this violates the spirit of what you're asking for).

Comment: @jcalz I mean changing typings only, not the function itself.

Comment: Ah, you should probably say you don't want the *runtime* behavior of the function to change, since "the function itself" doesn't necessarily convey your intent here.  But, unfortunately, this isn't possible without *partial type argument inference* as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242). If you want to get this behavior you will need to change how you call the function.  See the linked question and answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use currying as an alternative:

```
declare function namespaced<S extends Record<string, any>>(): <N extends keyof S>(namespace: N) => S[N];

let p = namespaced<Store>()("first");
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8LDEw)